# Shrinking and centering bootstrap 3 form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I'm working with bootstrap 3 and trying to piece together a base layout for a flask app. so far I have:

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="pull-middle">
                <h1 class="page-header">Create an awesome App template with Bootstrap.</h1>
                    <div class="container">
                    {% block content %}
                        {% endblock %}
                            </div>

                  <div class="panel panel-default ">
                    <div class="panel-body ">
                        <form action="#" role="form col-xs-4">
                            <div class="input-group ">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" type="submit">Sign up for free</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

      <footer class="footer text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <small>© Copyright 2015. </small>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I want to shrink the email address form to 4-6 columns and center it (to about the size of the red square), leaving the green button as is. So far I've tried to add col-xs-4 to various classes based on http://jsfiddle.net/tX3ae/225/ , but have not figured out how to get this working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's row and column classes aren't designed to be added willy-nilly. Row elements should always only have column elements as their immediate children. Likewise, column elements should always be the immediate children of row elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="pull-middle">
          <h1 class="page-header">Create an awesome App template with Bootstrap.</h1>
          <div class="container">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
              <div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                  <form action="#" role="form">
                    <div class="input-group ">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" type="submit">Sign up for free</button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <small>© Copyright 2015. </small>
        </div>
      </footer>
    ...
```

Check out the docs for more details:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Sean, thank you. Would you mind a follow up question. I notice that the Email field is a little short. How would I increase its size maybe 50% while leaving the button the same?